# Posicionamiento divs CSS

Tags: html, css, div

Dispongo de un `div` **búsqueda** y quiero tener otro `div` **mostrar_cabañas**. Deseo que en el formulario, cual está dentro de **búsqueda**, si pulsamos **Buscar** se nos abra/cargue el `div` **mostrar_cabañas** y que éste aparezca debajo del `div` **búsqueda** con un pequeño espacio entra ambos `divs`...

**¿Cómo coloco un div debajo de otro div con css?**

Deseo que coloque cada cabana dentro de un `div` a su vez, cual `div` contendrá nombre de la cabaña, imágenes y sus opiniones.

**Código HTML/PHP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo1.jpg">
        <div class="busqueda">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

                <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>


        <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
            <!--Código si hemos pulsado el botón Buscar...-->
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
    /*background: #DEDEDE;*/
    display: flex; /*Centrado en la página tanto vertical como horizontal.*/
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed; /*Imagen de fondo no se vaya con el scroll de la página.*/
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
}

.busqueda{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    padding: 18px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

input{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    background: linear-gradient(#FFDA63, #FFB940);
    border: 0;
    width: 160px;
    color: brown;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

De inicio el `div` **búsqueda** se me centra en toda la página (TODO OK), cuando pulso "**Buscar**", me salen todas las cabañas disponibles pero al lado del `div` **búsqueda** y se me descentra todo.

**Solución posible:**

**1)** Lo que quiero es que al pulsar `button` **BUSCAR**, se nos genere el `div` **mostrar_cabanas** pero DEBAJO del `div` **búsqueda**.

**2)** Tengo de fondo una imagen para toda la página (incorporada en el `body`), ¿cómo haría independiente la imagen de fondo a la imagen de fondo de los `divs` **mostrar_cabanas**? Es decir, que el `div` **mostrar_cabanas** tenga el fondo blanco para poder visualizar bien los datos.

Imagen del problema: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahora mismo te aparece al lado como esta en la imagen. Verdad?

Comment: Así es. La imagen es el resultado final al pulsar BUSCAR dentro del div búsqueda. De inicio el div búsqueda se me centra perfectamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un `div` que sea en contenedor de ambos divs y `display:flex` se encargara de posicionarlos ambos en el centro de la pantalla:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
 /*background: #DEDEDE;*/
 display: flex; /*Centrado en la página tanto vertical como horizontal.*/
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed; /*Imagen de fondo no se vaya con el scroll de la página.*/
 -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
 -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
 -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
 background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
}
#contenedor{
   width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
}


.sesion_cliente{
 position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
 float: right; 
 text-align: right;
}

.negrita{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
}

a:visited {
    color: red;
}


.busqueda{
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
 max-width: 500px;
 background: #F3F3F3;
 padding: 18px;
 border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}



h2{
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

input{
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 30px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
 background: linear-gradient(#FFDA63, #FFB940);
 border: 0;
 width: 160px;
 color: brown;
 opacity: 0.8;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}


.form-link{
 font-size: 12px;
}

.mostrar_cabanas{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo1.jpg">
      <div id="contenedor">
         <div class="busqueda">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

                <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                </div>
            </form>
        
      </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>


        <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
          RESULTADO DE LA BUSQUEDA
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El problema que si elimino la propiedad display:flex, no se me centra el div de búsqueda... Y se me coloca centrado horizontalmente pero NO verticalmente.

Comment: @omaza1990 Lo logras aplicandole la misma regla que el css del formulario. Acabo de editar la respuesta con los nuevos estilos del contenedor de los resultados.

Comment: Me has entendido mal. No me refiero a centrar .mostrar_cabanas, sino a centrar el cuadro de RESERVAR, donde pide la fecha de entrada y fecha de salida. Ese formulario se me centra horizontalmente pero no verticalmente

Comment: @omaza1990 Te fieres al texto dentro del fomulario que no salen centrados? Porque el div del form me aparece centrado verticalmente.

Comment: No me refiero al CUADRO, al div "busqueda" que sale justo pegado al margen superior y no sale centrado en la página HTML.

Comment: @omaza1990 Puedes enviarme una imagen de como se te ve a ti? En mi navegador utlizando chrome, me aparcen ambos divs centrados, tantos horizontal como vertical, ambos en el medio. Quizas estoy entiendo mal y una imagen me ayude.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70765/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-einer).